# Problema al momentos de manejar algunos datos de un dataframe python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Debo consultar los contratos con mayor valor de un dataframe. Para esto, se debe crear un nuevo DataFrame a partir del original, el cual contenga la información de los 10 contratos con mayor valor en el DataFrame.

De cada contrato, solo nos interesa la información de las siguientes 4 columnas: entidad contratante, departamento de la entidad, nombre del proveedor al cual se adjudicó el contrato y valor del contrato

Importo las librerías y cargo el dataframe todo:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
archivo = pd.read_csv("2019.csv")
```

Creo un nuevo dataframe con las columnas que necesito :

```
valorC = archivo.loc[:, ["NombreEntidad","Departamento","ProveedorAdjudicado","ValordelContrato"]]
```

Recorro todo el dataframe `valorC` **necesitando que muestre 10 filas de los contratos más caros** y no sé si lo este haciendo bien:

```
for i in range(len(valorC.iloc[0:10])):
    print("Nombre Entidad:\n"+ valorC.loc[i,"NombreEntidad"]+" Departamento: \n"+valorC.loc[i,"Departamento"]+" Nombre del proveedor: \n"+valorC.loc[i,"ProveedorAdjudicado"]+"Valor del contrato: \n"+str(valorC.loc[i,"ValordelContrato"]))
```

Me gustaria saber como podríoa hacerlo o que faltaría.
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes combinar las técnicas de **indexing** con el método `.sort_values()`. Primero voy a **crear un DataFrame de ejemplo** como el tuyo:

```
import pandas as pd
import string

valorC = pd.DataFrame({
    "NombreEntidad": [i for i in string.ascii_uppercase],
    "Departamento": [i for i in string.ascii_lowercase],
    "ProveedorAdjudicado": [i for i in string.ascii_uppercase],
    "ValordelContrato": range(0, 52, 2)
})
```

Ahora tenemos:

```
    NombreEntidad   Departamento    ProveedorAdjudicado ValordelContrato
0   A   a   A   0
1   B   b   B   2
2   C   c   C   4
3   D   d   D   6
...  ...  ...  ...  ...
```

### Solución

```
valorC.sort_values(["ValordelContrato"], ascending=False)[:10]
```

1. `.sort_values(["ValordelContrato"], ascending=False)`: indicamos que queremos **ordenar el DataFrame** mediante la columna `ValordelContrato` y en **orden descendente**
2. `[:10]`:  indicamos que coja **solo los 10 primeros valores**

**Salida:**

```
NombreEntidad   Departamento    ProveedorAdjudicado ValordelContrato
25  Z   z   Z   50
24  Y   y   Y   48
23  X   x   X   46
22  W   w   W   44
...  ...  ...  ...  ...
```

### Bonus

Como regla general `Pandas` trae sus propio métodos y funciones para operar ya que trata de imitar a `SQL` por lo que muy rara vez es necesario hacer bucles.